# Problems in dynamic algorithms in computational geometry

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, ds.algorithms, cg.comp-geom

The publication of Chiang and Tamassia's [paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=6A84CE6A6AAFAADE17FA3608269BF318?doi=10.1.1.50.8622&rep=rep1&type=pdf) on dynamic algorithms in computational geometry included several algorithms used in solving dynamic computational geometry problems such as:

- Dynamic Range Searching
- Dynamic Point Enclosure
- Dynamic Set Intersection

And others.

What are some open problems in dynamic computational geometry currently that have good static algorithms but worse dynamic algorithms? I am especially interested in algorithms that use priority queues in the static solution.